# Finding index within specific selector descendants

Tags: jquery, indexing, descendant

My simplified scenario:

```
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to find index of class="selected" within class="content" for each class="container", so the expected results for the above scenario would be:

```
0, 1
```

I'm trying to achieve this with jQuerys 'each' function like so:

```
$('.container').each(function()
{
  $(this).find('.item').index('.selected'); 
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .item').index('.selected');
  $(this).find('.selected').index();
});
```

But I'm getting only -1 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the index of the `.selected` amongst its siblings, which is what [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) gives you if you call it on the element without arguments. So in your `each`:

```
$(this).find(".content .selected").index()
```

...gives you the index of the selected element.

Live Example:

```js
$(".container").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find(".content .selected").index());
});
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could even get an array of those indexes by using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), returning the index out of the callback, and using [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to turn the jQuery result into a true array:

```
var indexes = $(".container").map(function() {
  return $(this).find(".content .selected").index();
}).get();
```

Live Example:

```js
var indexes = $(".container").map(function() {
  return $(this).find(".content .selected").index();
}).get();
console.log(indexes);
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you want index of `.selected` against it's siblings,so do like below:-

```js
$('.container .content').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).children('.selected').index()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, using `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
const index_arr = $(".container").toArray()
  .map(e=>$(e).find(".item").toArray())
  .reduce((acc, arr)=>{
    arr.forEach((e, i)=>{
      if($(e).hasClass("selected"))
        acc.push(i);
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
```